# GPS device returning bad output in Android on a cloudy day

Tags: android, gps, android-location

On a cloudy day, what will be the output of a GPS device?

Comment: you have accepted a wrong answer, GPS is well known to not be affected by cloudy wheather. You should upvote the correct answers.

Comment: May be @AlexWien is right. Accept his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definitive way of knowing if cloudy weather affects the GPS's *performance*. Additionally, if we were to assume it does affect it, there is no way of knowing for sure what effect it has on the output.

GPS performance also changes from device to device. (I speak purely in this context of Android devices). The 1st generation Samsung Galaxy S is know for it's terrible GPS performance. To the extent that a cursory search on XDA will reveal several attempted *fixes* plus a few hardware mods too.

In my opinion, however, your statement that cloudy weather affects the GPS performance is a **common myth** among plenty of GPS users. The first source clearly states that the loss when using GPS in cloudy conditions is a mere 2db. Hardly enough to affect it's performance as you state it does in your app.

Source 1: http://www.gpsinformation.net/gpsclouds.htm

Source 2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System

Extract from Source 2:

> The Global Positioning System (GPS) is a space-based satellite
>   navigation system that provides location and time information in all
>   weather conditions, anywhere on or near the Earth where there is an
>   unobstructed line of sight to four or more GPS satellites.

**A possible solution:** If you think GPS is affected by the weather conditions, you could consider using the Network provider to ensure *seamless* performance in your app.

Comment: Now it only checks the gps device is enabled or not during the cloudy season if it is enabled and return some kind of output like 0.0,0.0 and it won't use the network provider and giving a bad result with this location for that i am asking you to what is the exact value returns the gps when it can't communicate with the satellites

Comment: @agen451: If it fails to get a location, then yes. The value would be **0.00000**, **0.00000**. But the result still _cannot be attributed to bad weather_.

Comment: you are missinterpreting the gps info site. cloudy wheater does not affect the GPS position.

Comment: @AlexWien: did you really read the post and the website. I say essentially the same thing. Down vote all you want, but read clearly before doing so.

Comment: Read your first sentence, it is wrong, there is a defintive way, but probably not for evryone.

Comment: @AlexWien: I do not wish to indulge in a war of words, but if you think there is an alternative which is in fact, definitive, I would like to see it. I'm out.

Comment: @AlexWien:Some devices example(htc) having less powered gps hardwares. so it will take much more time when it is cloudy weather that is i meant.Any way i also do not wish to indulge in a war of words.

Comment: @agen451 where do you get your information from? if it will take more time this has nothing to do with cloudy wheather.

Answer (score 2):

from the link http://www.gpsreview.net/10-myths-about-gps/

People often describe GPS receivers as needing a “clear view of the sky”, however the clear view simply replies to not having any obstructions to the view of the sky such as mountains, tall buildings, dense canopy, etc. A cloudy day will not prevent your GPS from working. As an example of this, airplanes can use GPS to navigate down to a runway in cloudy or foggy conditions.

Comment: upvoted, because more correct than the current acepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I can garuantee, that the GPS signal is not affected by cloudy wheather. GPS is weather proof. A GPS signal has to travel from the satellite through the ionosphere to the receiver. on that way the weather part (where the clouds are located) is a very small band at the end of that path.
GPS is more affected by the sun. At night the signal is slightly better, because the sun causes electrmnagnetic disturbance.

The frequency of the GPS signal is choosen to be outside of the range where water molecules can weaken the signal.

So finally your problem was for sure not caused by cloudy wheather.
The only thing related to weather are wet leafes of trees, which weakens the GPS signals.
(Some receiver have a forrest mode for that purpose)